# How to use TRAMP over tor?

Tags: tramp, ssh

I am not able to use TRAMP mode over tor. When I try to use something like M-x `ssh://blabloblu.onion` it just doesn't work.

```
tramp-signal-hook-function: Tramp failed to connect.  If this happens repeatedly, try
    ‘M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection’
```

Comment: Can you connect via ssh over Tor outside of Emacs?

Comment: `M-x ssh://blabloblu.onion` looks strange. Typo?

Comment: @Tyler yes. Michael Albinus I just elided the onion address to "blabloblu".